# Is there any way to see which questions have the highest views for a site?

Tags: discussion, questions

[One of my Arqade Questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136182/how-many-endings-are-in-the-2013-edition-of-the-stanley-parable) has an insane whopping 323K views - more than many of the top-voted questions of the site.

I doubt that it's the highest-viewed question on the site itself, but I'd like to see how it stacks up against the other questions.

Is there any way to see a site's questions ranked by number of views?   I would like to see how many questions are higher-ranked in view count than mine, and by how many views they outrank my own question.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/294849/sort-questions-by-views is the option here :)

Comment: @nicael While I'm looking for something that is in SE itself rather than a query on SE info, that **is** the data I'm looking for, and I'd gladly upvote such a comment as an answer.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ That's a good sort (the question that THAT question is a duplicate of) but it doesn't provide the actual view count of the questions that it returns - which is what I'm really looking for.  I much prefer the results nicael provided.

Comment: @Zibbobz: It seems nicael is not in a position to post an answer. You should probably post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As @nicael suggested, the [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used to create a query that will return a result set with this information.  The query to use is:

> select top 500 id as [Post Link], ViewCount
>
> from posts
>
> order by ViewCount desc

Which will [return](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/294849/sort-questions-by-views) a list of the top 500 highest-viewed questions.  From there, you can choose any SE site you wish to query for your results.